# Add plugin mathjax for tinymce 4

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4, mathjax, tinymce-plugins

I want to add plugin mathjax for tinymce 4.Because now we can not find mathjax for tinymce 4 but only for tinymce 3. help

Comment: The very first google search result for "_tinymce mathjax_" is a plugin for TinyMCE 4.

Comment: I have searched a lot but all of it is not suitable or error.